# Cannot install dependencies with apt-get build-dep

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, compiling

I am trying to install build dependencies for `qt` with the command `sudo apt-get build-dep qtbase5-dev` following [this](https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Build_from_source/Install_the_dependencies) guide. The output of apt command listed below:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'qtbase-opensource-src' as source package instead of 'qt5-default'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
builddeps:qtbase-opensource-src : Depends: libfontconfig1-dev but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libfreetype6-dev but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libgtk2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: libpng-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried apt's `autoclean`, `autoremove`, `update`, `upgrade`, `dist-upgrade` and so on. Nothing works for me. Can you please help me.
I use:

```
Linux ASUS 4.10.0-37-generic #41~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 6 22:42:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Run apt-cache policy on those 4 & if desired post the results here in or in a pastebin, ( https://paste.ubuntu.com/ ) & post link. As far as libpng-dev there is no actual package by that name, it's a virtual package. `apt-cache policy libfontconfig1-dev libgtk2.0-dev libfreetype6-dev libpng*-dev`

Comment: Random apt commands won't help, and are sometimes counter productive. It's not an apt bug - you created a puzzle that you need to *solve*, like a knotted shoelace. Usually, 'held broken' packages indicates a *version conflict* caused by shoddy PPAs or other non-Ubuntu sources. Use `apt cache policy` like @doug said to determine if that's the case, or if you have a different problem.